# Abstracting code on android studio module. Architectural guidance needed

Tags: android, android-studio, aar

I have a project that contains a module with linear layouts, views etc., in them. I would like to convert that into a library and abstract that code so if i decide to give to another person to develop, they dont see that code.
When I tried to make a library instead, I am seeing errors like "cannot find symbol class R" etc.,

I guess that is because of the fact that if I make it a library, it does not support layouts?

How can I get around the issue? Bottom line would be that I would need to separate out a module and give an abstracted code out to another person. (Probably like an AAR) is that possible? How can I do the same?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

An Android Archive Library (aar) can contains as many resources as an app can (images, strings, dimens, colors, layouts) and can contains classes like custom views, compound views, activities, fragments, etc.

You can also include some external dependencies in your library and use them as an internal resource or even provide that library to the app through your library.

About the `R` class, maybe you need to check all your layouts or classes and remove the import `R` from the previous app module and import the new `R` from the library module.